# VHDL Event vs. Transaction

Tags: vhdl

I can't figure out this issue.  In my test bench I am checking timing to make sure I have adequate separation of data/addr setup to the enable pulse edges in terms of clock delays, not logic delays.  I am finding a timing violation on this test.

```
      assert ((LCD_E_rise - LCD_RS'Last_event) >= ST7066U_tAS) 
                OR (LCD_RS'Last_event > now)
        report Rgt_Lft & " tAS not met for LCD_RS, " &
          time'image(LCD_E_rise-LCD_RS'Last_event) &
          ", LCD_RS'Last_event = " & time'image(LCD_RS'Last_event)
          & ", LCD_E_rise = " & time'image(LCD_E_rise) 
        severity failure;
```

The printout from this is:

```
# EXECUTION:: FAILURE: LEFT tAS not met for LCD_RS, -15228822 ps, LCD_RS'Last_event = 5030458392 ps, LCD_E_rise = 5015229570 ps
# EXECUTION:: Time: 5030488194 ps,  Iteration: 1,  Instance: /LCD_Drvr_tb,  Process: Disp_time.
# KERNEL: Stopped at time 5030488194 ps + 1.
```

The values printed out are saying LCD_RS is changing state 15 us after the rising edge of LCD_E_L (LCD_E_Lft or LCD_En in some procedures) which is one clock cycle before the falling edge of LCD_E_L which is what triggers the check.  The numbers add up just fine, but they say LCD_RS is changing and it is not.  Here is the code that updates LCD_RS.

```
  LCD_Out: process (Clk) is
  begin
    if (rising_edge(Clk)) then
      with Inst_State select LCD_RS <= 
            '1' when DDData_Top | DDData_Bot | CGR_Data, '0' when others;
      LCD_Row   <= '1' when (Inst_State = DDData_Bot) else '0';
      -- Select the commands or data for the LCD data input
      with Inst_State select LCD_Data <=
            LCD_MData       when DDData_Top | DDData_Bot | CGR_Data,
            FuncSetCmd      when F_Set_1 | F_Set_2,
            DispOnCmd       when Disp_ON,
            EntryModeCmd    when Ent_Mod, 
            DDRTopAddrCmd   when DDAddr_Top,
            DDRBotAddrCmd   when DDAddr_Bot,
            CGRAddrCmd      when CGR_Adr,
            DunCareCmd      when Cmd_Idl;
    end if;
  end process LCD_Out;
```

A screen capture of the time frame showing no transitions.
[image: Event issue]
The entire program with test bench is over 600 lines, so too much to post here. I can perhaps provide it through another location where the various files can be downloaded.

The only thing I can think is there is a transaction at that time, but not an event and the simulator is screwing up, Active-HDL by Aldec.  My previous problems with this tool have been related to VHDL-2008 support.  I don't think that's the issue here.

Any thoughts?

Adjusted the assert code to show a time variable assigned to now on events of LCD_RS.

````
      assert ((LCD_E_rise - LCD_RS'Last_event) >= ST7066U_tAS) 
                OR (LCD_RS'Last_event > now)
        report Rgt_Lft & " tAS not met for LCD_RS, " &
          time'image(LCD_E_rise-LCD_RS'Last_event) &
          ", LCD_RS'Last_event = " & time'image(LCD_RS'Last_event)
          & ", LCD_E_rise = " & time'image(LCD_E_rise) 
          & ", LCD_RS_event = " & time'image(LCD_RS_event)
        severity failure;```
````

```
if (LCD_RS'event) then -- Check hold time to enable, tAH
...
  LCD_RS_event := now;
end if;
```

```
The reported time for an event on LCD_RS from this variable is 30 ns into the simulation which is the first clock cycle where it gets a '0' value rather than a 'U' value.  The 'last_event value reported is one clock prior to the current simulation time which is when it is updated with another '0' value.  Clearly a bug conflating event with transaction. 

When I get both time to create a good test case and a means of accessing Lattice support I will report this bug.
```

Comment: I think I agree with your assessment. If you can boil it down to a 30 line reproducer add that to the question. But I'd suggest testing it on other simulators too (my trusty ghdl for a start!)